# TinyMCE - adding grids that are editable without the tags disappearing

Tags: tinymce

I have added a custom set of buttons for adding simple grids to the editor. These have the following structure;

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="col-1-2"><p>Column 1</p></div>
<div class="col-1-2"><p>Column 2</p></div>
</div>
```

A custom CSS assigned displays the grids correctly. However as soon as the user goes to edit the text..understandably by deleting it all or highlighting and trying to replace, TinyMCE immediately removes the empty tags so if the user deletes the text Column 1 we end up with this;

```
<div class="grid">my new text<br />
<div class="col-1-2"><p>Column 2</p></div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding;

```
extended_valid_elements : 'div[id|class|style]'
```

but it had no effect.

How can I stop TinyMCE from removing these empty tags or am I going about this the wrong way..?

Thanks

Comment: can you show me your tinymce configuration of valid_elements and valid_children?

Comment: I havent set up any valid_elements or children so its just the default..I am using 4.1 from CDN //tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js

Comment: upon further investigation it appears to have something to do with the floats in the style for the columns. If I create a couple of empty div elements they hang around, but if I create them with a float style then once I highlight the text and replace the parent floated div disappears.

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/rnfaab fiddle with floated elements. Two things that happen, if you double click either of the pieces of text it also highlights all or part of the other div contents and if you delete all the text the div is removed which doesnt happen if it doesnt have float

Comment: which browser are you using? i cannot see this behaviour in firefox

Comment: You're right it doesnt happen in Firefox or Edge, it also doesnt happen on Chrome if you use lower than version 4..http://fiddle.tinymce.com/rnfaab/4. No good for me. Anyone have any ideas..?